# Python Praw skipping sticky in subreddits

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to loop through subreddits, but want to ignore the sticky posts at the top.  I am able to print the first 5 posts, unfortunately including the stickies.  Various pythonic methods of trying to skip these have failed.  Two different examples of my code below.

```
            subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)
            for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=5):

                # If we haven't replied to this post before
                if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:
                    ##FOOD

                    if subreddit == 'food':

                        if 'pLEASE SEE' in submission.title:
                            pass
                        if "please vote" in submission.title:
                            pass
                        else:
                            print(submission.title)
                        if re.search("please vote", submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                            pass
                        else:

                            print(submission.title)
```

I noticed a sticky tag in the documents but not sure exactly how to use it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make the strings lowercase and check against `submission.title.lower()`

Comment: Could you print out the titles you are comparing against and note which ones are stickies? That would help with debugging the regex side of things. Otherwise use @al-avery's answer.

Comment: I highly recommend reading a basic Python tutorial before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like you can get the id of a stickied post based on docs](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=sticky).  So perhaps you could get the id(s) of the stickied post(s) (note that with the 'number' parameter of the sticky method you can say give me the first, or second, or third, stickied post; use this to your advantage to get *all* of the stickied posts) and for each submission that you are going to pull, first check its id against the stickied ids.

Example:

```
# assuming there are no more than three stickies...
stickies = [reddit.subreddit("chicago").sticky(i).id for i in range(1,4)]
```

and then when you want to make sure a given post isn't stickied, use:

```
if post.id not in stickies:
    do something
```

It looks like, were there fewer than three, this would give you a list with duplicate ids, which won't be a problem.

Comment: Actually, it will raise `prawcore.NotFound` if there are fewer than 3 instead of returning duplicate IDs according to the docs.

Comment: Interesting.  That behavior would make a lot more sense to me, but I tested it out and it actually does not seem to.  Rather, if you do `r.subreddit("chicago").sticky(3)` but r/chicago only has two stickies, it'll give you the id of the second sticky.  In fact, you can do `r.subreddit("chicago").sticky(-94)` and it'll give you the id of sticky number one; it seems to just give you the id of the closest match.  Although, i don't know what would happen if you tried htis and there were no stickies at all.

Answer (score 3):

Submissions which are stickied have a `sticked` attribute that evaluates to `True`. Add the following to your loop, and you should be good to go.

```
if submission.stickied:
    continue
```

In general, I recommend checking the available attributes on the objects you are working with to see if there is something usable. See: [Determine Available Attributes of an Object](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to @Al Avery's answer, you can do a complete search for the IDs of all stickies on a given subreddit by doing something like

```
def get_all_stickies(sub):
    stickies = set()
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        try:
            sid = sub.sticky(i)
        except pawcore.NotFound:
            break
        if sid in stickies:
            break
        stickies.add(sid)
    return stickies
```

This function takes into account that the documentation lead one to expect an error if an invalid index is supplied to `stick`, while the actual behavior seems to be that a duplicate ID is returned. Using a `set` instead of a list makes lookup faster if you have a large number of stickies. You would use the function as

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)
stickies = get_all_stickies(subreddit)
for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=5):
    if submission.id not in posts_replied_to and submission.id not in stickies:
        print(submission.title)
```

Comment: Unfortunaly it considers every post as a sticky now.                                  stickies = get_all_stickies(reddit.subreddit(str(subreddit)))
                                if stickies:
                                    print(stickies)
                                    print(submission.title)
                                else:
                                    print("not a sticky: " + submission.title)

Comment: @Eddwinn. That's because you are not using it right. See update. `get_all_stickies` returns a set with all the sticky IDs. You test for containment using `in`, same as you are doing with `posts_replied_to`.