# How do I exclude sticky submissions using PRAW?

Tags: python, praw, reddit

I'm trying to get the top submission from a subreddit which is not sticky.

Tried something like this:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xx', client_secret='yy', user_agent='zz')
submissions = reddit.subreddit('theSubreddit').hot(limit=1, sticky=True)
```

But it doesn't work, only returning an error saying `sticky` is not a valid argument. How can I achieve this? I'm using PRAW version 4.3.0

Note I have [cross-posted this question here](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/5rp76p/praw_how_do_i_exclude_sticky_submissions/).

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41861138/1712600) posted earlier, but this is different. In my case, the `limit` is `1`. I'm only targeting the top non-sticky submission. So, manually checking `submission.stickied` inside a loop will not return me anything if the top submission is a sticky one.

Comment: So it looks like you need to get the submissions first and then get the stick-ied submissions and compare those two lists. I would think that you would have to do something like the answer you have provided. Such as, get submissions then `if submission.stickied:
    continue`

Comment: @Alastair thanks for the reply. I was looking for a simpler way and I think I got that! Will add that as an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the [solution from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/5rp76p/praw_how_do_i_exclude_sticky_submissions/dd91fe2/) where I posted this same question. Thanks to the Reddit user **bboe**.

```
submission = next(x for x in reddit.subreddit('theSubreddit').hot() if not x.stickied)
```

Surely this is not an iterable object / Array which I was previously getting.
This is just a single object where I don't need to iterate to get its properties.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement.